# Prestashop 1.7 - My translation does not appear in the translation interface

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on a module on prestashop 1.7.

I'm doing the translation but I have a problem on the front office.
My back office strings appear in the translation interface, but not of the front office.

I have in my tpl file of the front office for example :

```
<tr>
    <th>{l s='Name of the category' d='mynewmodule'}</th>
    <th>{l s='Select' d='mynewmodule'}</th>
</tr>
```

But nothing appears in the translation interface.
I'm fine in: Translations -> Installed modules translations -> mynewmodule

But nothing (except those of the back office)

Thank you for your help. Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you have to use the 'old' system.

```
{l s='Name of the category' mod='mynewmodule'}
```

This is all for the moment. The developers are working to move all the translations system to the new 'embedded' system of symfony.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate text by prestashop 1.7 translation system please follow this :

// Your modules name must be start `ps_`.
// Your modules name should be appear after prestashop translation domain name.

// You can get all prestashop domain from `print_r($this->context->getTranslator()->getCatalogue()->all())` to this code.

// If the domain name is `shoppingcart` then your orginal module name should be `ps_shoppingcart` .

// after that IF you used  `{l s='translate text' d='domain'}` this system on your that module then it will translate prestashop 1.7.x.x system.

// You can see the prestashop core code here : `root\controllers\admin\AdminTranslationsController.php this file` `isUsingNewTranslationsSystem()` function .